# how to convert uploaded image to byte array javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, multipart

```
i want to upload images to the server using ajax post request , here my question was how to convert image to a byte array for sending image to the server as multipart how can i achieve this.


here I posted what I tried:

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 form-group">
                            <label>Attachement</label>
                            <input id="other_fileUpload_create" type="file" class="form-pcontrol">
                        </div>
```

Ajax:

```
  var formData = new FormData();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseURL + '/misportal/ptwRest/saveIsolation',
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: function() {

              //  var inputs = $('#IsolationFO').serializeArray();

 //here i got image path instead of byte array  

             formData.append("Image",$('#other_fileUpload_create').val());


                return formData;
            }(),
```

Comment: Does `.val()` from jquery on a input element return a FILE object,. if so and you just sending a single image, no need to use FormData as that add unnecessary overhead.  Just send the file object to the `data` property.

Comment: can you give me asample code beacuse iam new to this @Keith